# Paper trail gem makes fields with the name version unusable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I have a table named `clients` backed by an AR model `Client`. This is the structure of `clients` table:

```
clients
  - id <serial primary key>
  - name <varchar(255)>
  - version <varchar(255)>
```

I have added versioning to it using the paper trail gem. However, when I update or create the record, the column `version` does not update. And when I do `Client.first.version` it gives me `nil` value even though all my records in the table have a `version` column that is not null or empty. I suspect this is because of paper trail gem. When I switch my project's branch to a version that does not use the gem, I am able to get non-nil value of version.

Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, there is. Problem is, [`version` is the default](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/model_config.rb#L111) association name in paper_trail, thus calling the association on client rather than fetching it's attribute. 
You can change your model as:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail version: :paper_version, versions: :paper_versions
end

c = Client.first
c.version #=> row field
c.paper_versions #=> previous versions.
```

**Edit:** Just found that it is also documented in paper_trail here - https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#6-extensibility

Comment: This is it! But the new names need to symbols: `has_paper_trail version: :paper_version, versions: :paper_versions`

Comment: In the current version (v11) of paper_trail passing versions association name as `has_paper_trail versions: :paper_trail_versions` is deprecated. Use `has_paper_trail versions: {name: :paper_trail_versions}` instead.